# R extract coefficients from regression models add string and create dataframe using lapply and sprintf

Tags: r, dataframe, lapply

Lets say I have multiple models (two survival and logistic here for convenience) and I just want to look at `sex` estimates.

```
library(survival)
data(colon)
sn <- Surv(colon$time, colon$status)
fit <- coxph(sn ~ sex + perfor + age, data = colon)
fit1 <- coxph(sn ~ sex + perfor + surg + rx , data = colon)
fit2 <- glm(factor(status) ~ sex + age, data=colon, family=binomial(link = "logit")) 
fit3 <- glm(factor(status) ~ sex + age + nodes, data=colon, family=binomial(link = "logit"))
```

I want the following dataframe (`df`) as my final output with model name and estimate. I also want a modified version of `df`, `df2`, so that there is a grouping effect where logistic and survival models are in different columns. The fact that they are ordered (2 survival followed by 2 logistic) makes this easier. Is there a way to extend this to a more general form and pre-define the layout of the dataset, lets say we had five models of survival/logistic/lme so we need 5 rows x 3 column type dataset.

```
> df
  model                    estimate
1   fit 0.97 (95 % CI 0.85 to 1.10)
2  fit1 0.94 (95 % CI 0.83 to 1.07)
3  fit2 0.97 (95 % CI 0.81 to 1.17)
4  fit3 0.98 (95 % CI 0.81 to 1.18)
```

and also

```
> df2
  model_survival                sur_estimate model_logistic           logistic_estimate
1            fit 0.97 (95 % CI 0.85 to 1.10)           fit2 0.97 (95 % CI 0.81 to 1.17)
2           fit1 0.94 (95 % CI 0.83 to 1.07)           fit3 0.98 (95 % CI 0.81 to 1.18)
```

My attempt so far:
I have used `lapply` which I think is better than a `for loop` and have pretty much worked it out but I would like the section that is outside lapply, to be inside so it is more automated if I had more models etc. See below.

```
mylist<-list(fit,fit1,fit2,fit3)
results <- list()
results <- lapply(mylist, function(x) {
  sprintf("%.2f (95 %% CI %.2f to %.2f)",     
          exp(coef(x))["sex"], 
          exp(confint(x)[,1])["sex"], 
          exp(confint(x)[,2])["sex"])
})          
results <- do.call(rbind.data.frame, results)
```

I can make `results` to look like `df` by doing the following but I would like this inside `lapply` so I don't need to get names again, just use them from mylist etc. but `results$model<-names(mylist)` doesn't work.

```
colnames(results)[1]<-"estimate"
results$model<-c("fit","fit1","fit2","fit3")
```

To get `df2` I could do some long to wide conversion but can I pre-define the layout and column names inside `lapply` (I know I will probably need two separate `lapply` - one for `df` and `df2`). Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `map` with `stack`

```
library(tidyverse)
out <- mget(ls(pattern = "fit\\d*")) %>% 
        map(~sprintf("%.2f (95 %% CI %.2f to %.2f)",     
           exp(coef(.x))["sex"], 
           exp(confint(.x)[,1])["sex"], 
           exp(confint(.x)[,2])["sex"])) %>%
        stack %>%
        select(model = ind, estimate = values)
out
#  model                    estimate
#1   fit 0.97 (95 % CI 0.85 to 1.10)
#2  fit1 0.94 (95 % CI 0.83 to 1.07)
#3  fit2 0.97 (95 % CI 0.81 to 1.17)
#4  fit3 0.98 (95 % CI 0.81 to 1.18)
```

From the 'out', we can get the second output

```
library(data.table)#using dcast as it can take multiple value.vars
out %>%
   group_by(group = rep(c("model_survival", "model_logistic"), each = 2)) %>%
   mutate(rn = row_number()) %>%
   as.data.table %>%
   dcast(., rn ~ group, value.var = c('model', 'estimate')) %>% 
   select(-rn)
# model_model_logistic model_model_survival     estimate_model_logistic     estimate_model_survival
#1:                 fit2                  fit 0.97 (95 % CI 0.81 to 1.17) 0.97 (95 % CI 0.85 to 1.10)
#2:                 fit3                 fit1 0.98 (95 % CI 0.81 to 1.18) 0.94 (95 % CI 0.83 to 1.07)
```

Comment: Perfect, learnt a lot there. What about df2 if we had say multiple columns wanted, is the easiest thing just to work from your dataset solution and create another one (say long to wide format) or is there someway to incorporate into your function?

Comment: @user63230  yes, it can done.  Do you want to automatically determine the logit or we manually apply it

Comment: @user63230  Updated the output.  Please check if it works for you

Comment: @user63230  Please check the wide format I just updated

Comment: One follow up question, would you know how to put an automated asterisk after the confidence interval within `sprinf` to indicate a statistical significant estimate perhaps using `symnum`?

Comment: @user63230  If you need the asterisk based on  pvalues, check `stars.pval` from [gtools](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/gtools/versions/3.5.0/topics/stars.pval)

Comment: If we make a list instead, `lst<-list(fit<-fit,fit1<-fit1,fit2<-fit2,fit3<-fit3)` why doesn't stack work? `out <- lst %>% 
  map(~sprintf("%.2f (95 %% CI %.2f to %.2f)",     
               exp(coef(.x))["sex"], 
               exp(confint(.x)[,1])["sex"], 
               exp(confint(.x)[,2])["sex"])) %>%
  stack`

Comment: @user63230  You are using `<-` instead of `fit1 = fit1`

Comment: i need sleep, sorry!